# Why using k-fold CV instead of train, test set “validation”

Tags: cross-validation

I've read a lot about CV with k fold and CV in general. Also implemented these in python. But yet, I still cannot answer this question:

Why using k-fold CV is better than:

Training on the entire train-set with various models and selecting the best model with respect to **train-set** accuracy.

Training on the entire train-set with various models and selecting the best model with respect to **test-set** accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a predictor or dependent variable similar to this:

```
2.9  2.8  2.3  2.8  2.5  15.0  3.0 2.7 18.0 2.4 2.6 ...
```

Everything seems well behaved with only two large outliers. If we have a smallish testing set and just by chance the two outliers fall within that small testing set they will influence that testing set a lot and there is going to be a bad fit because both outliers contorted the testing set.

If we split the same data into $k$ sets chances are higher, that both do not within the same group and if they do, the bad situation with both outliers in the same smallish testing set will affect only one out of $k$ test runs.

Answer (score 1):

> selecting the best model with respect to train-set accuracy

... will result in overfitting

> selecting the best model with respect to test-set accuracy

... This will to a certain extent guard against overfitting, but

- you'll need yet another data set to estimate generalization error - the test-set accuracy after selecting for this very same criterion also has an optimistic bias
- ovefitting due to model selection depends (among other influencing factors) on variance uncertainty in the figure of merit the selection is based on. The test set uses fewer test cases than cross validation (which uses *all* available cases in turn) and is therefore subject to higher uncertainty (see @Bernhard's illustrative example). So with cross validation, theres also a somewhat lower risk of overfitting than splitting the data that is in principle available for training only one further time.